# Why file access is denied

Tags: c#, file

I have the following code which...

- Checks if a folder exists
- If it exists, check if a file exists
- if file exists, read all the lines from the file
- once all the line has been read, show the length of the line in a messagebox

Code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    strPath = @"C:\QRXS";
    string strFile = @"C:\QRXS\download.lst";
    if (Directory.Exists(strPath))
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(strFile))
            {
                try
                {
                    ln = File.ReadAllLines(strPath);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // inform user or log depending on your usage scenario
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "FILE ACCESS");
                }

                if (ln != null)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ln.Length + "");
                    // do something with lines
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ce)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ce.Message, "FOLDER ACCESS");
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime I run the application (used `Run as Administrator` as well), the following line keeps being invoked:

`MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "FILE ACCESS");`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace:

```
File.ReadAllLines(strPath);
```

with:

```
File.ReadAllLines(strFile);
```

Reason: `strPath` denotes a directory. You're trying to read its contents as if it were a file, and that obviously won't work.

Comment: WOW... I am blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use :

```
File.ReadAllLines(strFile);
```

Comment: Some other dude beat you to it bro

Comment: he was a little bit faster than me :))))

Comment: Yes... unfortunately it's not fair that I can only pick one answer but then he was first... Thank you regardless.